# PageContext over ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Our application uses ViewState for storing page level variables. We are planning to migrate the same to use PageContext. Are there any drawbacks of Page Context over ViewState or vice versa.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "PageContext"? Can you provide a link (nomen est omen ;-))?

Comment: do u mean Page? Context http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context.aspx

Comment: Yes I am referring to Page.Context. It has an Items collection which can be exploited to persist page level variables across postbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context objects can persist across pages. 
Only on a Server.Transfer will Context.Items collection persist. 
A Response.Redirect is a postback and Context objects do not survive postbacks...
But guess what does survive postbacks
Postbacks   Server.Transfer
Context.Items   No  Yes
View State  Yes No

So a common combo technique I've seen is: Starting in Page A storing an object in Context, navigating to a another Page B (via Server.Transfer) and assuming that Page B may involve some postback at some point, reading the Context object into ViewState.

Can refer this link
http://dotnetjeet.com/post/ContextItems-vs-ViewState.aspx